# Spring Boot Integration Test - BeanDefinitionOverrideException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring Boot Integration test with a class defined as follows.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestApplication.class})
@Transactional
public class AuthorisationManagerControllerRequestIT
{
...
```

I get the below Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionAdvisor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]] for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
```

My TestApplication class it is defined as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = Application.class)
})
@ImportResource({
        "classpath:properties-context.xml"          
})
public class TestApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

It reads from properties-context.xml which is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="${CONFIG.ROOT}/external.properties"/>


</beans>
```

This reads from a file called external.properties. I have the property 'spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true' set in my external properties file.  I added this because when I was running the application before this same Exception was appearing, but no longer appears after adding this.

What is needed to stop this Exception appearing in my Integration Test?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that seems logical given your error:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException` is thrown when spring is creating a bean with the same name as one already created. And the properties `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`, which has been turned off by default for Spring-boot 2, is made to allow you bean override.

Which I don't understand is why you have 2 beans with the same regarding Transactions...